# Can I change super global variables with nodejs like I do with php?

Tags: php, ajax, node.js, cors, superglobals

Can I change super global variables with nodejs like I do with php ?

And if not, then can anyone point me to an easy tutorial about how to do cross domain http request from the client ? You know, the CORS that block ajax to another domain ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a framework like Express, [CORS can be done like this](http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // Handle the get for this route
});

app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
 // Handle the post for this route
});
```

Or, even easier, use the [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) middleware.

Or, to roll your own, you can use [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nilcolor/816580) as a starting point:

```
if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
      console.log('!OPTIONS');
      var headers = {};
      // IE8 does not allow domains to be specified, just the *
      // headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = req.headers.origin;
      headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
      headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS";
      headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = false;
      headers["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = '86400'; // 24 hours
      headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept";
      res.writeHead(200, headers);
      res.end();
} else {
//...other requests
}
```

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.atomedge.org/ajax.php. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: I believe you would need to include the Allow-Origin in the `else` branch too for requests for which you wish to enable CORS. The gist only shows how to get the `OPTIONS` requests handled correctly.

Comment: I was adding CORS option on the wrong domain lol. All I had to do was add a Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "*"; in the php page. Do I get a point for marking your answer as good ?